# Изменение списка python

Tags: python, list, for

Можете ли пояснить, почему в коде (написан для примера) вроде всё логически нормально, но по итогу список не изменяется. При этом если использовать обращение через  индекс посредством Items.index(Item) то всё работает. Вроде как код написанный ниже должен работать и так, где я ошибся?

```
Items = ["weapon","offhand","helmet","boots","belt","offhand","gloves","bonus"]
for Item in Items:
    Item += "1234"
print(Items)
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Потому что вы изменяете только значение переменной `Item`, которая не имеет никакой связи с исходным списком

Comment: В таком случае как сделать правильно? без костыля в виде обращения по индексу

Comment: А почему обращение по индексу это костыль? И какова ваша реальная задача?

Comment: А приведённый в вопросе код можно переписать например так `Items = [Item + "1234" for Item in Items]`

Comment: По сути задача - изменить каждый объект списка ( или отдельный объект) не пользуясь обращением через индекс.

Comment: Строки невозможно изменять, можно только создавать новые строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант обновления списка без индексов. Так как список хранит строки, а строки неизменны, то в обычном цикле `for Item in Items:` обновить список нельзя. Можно создать новый временный и заместить элементы старого. Вот так:

```
Items = ["weapon","offhand","helmet","boots","belt","offhand","gloves","bonus"]
Items[:] = [Item + "1234" for Item in Items]
```

Важно понимать разницу между `Items =`  и `Items[:] =` . Первое присваивание удаляет старый список и присваивает переменной новый. Второе присваивание в старом списке изменяет элементы. Сам список не удаляется.